# getting to phpmyadmin with mamp

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm using MAMP, and trying to get to phpmyadmin. loaclhost/phpmyadmin isn't working.. the sql light is green so it is enabled.

I have changed the Document Root to /Users/troycosentino/Sites/easyuniv/ and when i open the start page from MAMP it is a page created by apple it looks like, not MAMP.

Any ideas?

Comment: The SQL light does not have anything to do with whether or not PHPMyAdmin is enabled, FWIW.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If i go to localhost:8888/MAMP it gives me the MAMP screen, from which i can go to phpmadmin.

Comment: I had to change port to that one set in the Preferences for Apache.

Comment: thanks.. my mamp froze so i had to use this to access db.

Answer (score 27):

If MAMP has MySQL Server and Apache Server running.
You can go to phpMyAdmin via url `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/`

Comment: for windows, I didn't need the port but just want to note that the case is very important (phpmyadmin does not work but phpMyAdmin does)

Answer (score 10):

Try this localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English

Click on phpMyAdmin tab and you have it.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows pay attention to capital letters:

```
http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/
```

Answer (score 5):

You can directly access it at the link below, make sure that it contains the same uppercase letters.

```
127.0.0.1/phpMyAdmin
```

Or if you prefer

```
localhost/phpMyAdmin
```

Answer (score 5):

On macOS MAMP, you need to go to

```
http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/?lang=en
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
localhost/MAMP
```

and from nav-menu choose: *tools>PhpMyAdmin*

Answer (score 0):

My htdocs folder was only filled with personal projects.

I have no idea WHY this works, but it did for me:

In the httpd.conf folder (do a command + space and search for that if you don't know what it is already), change your root folder to:

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/bin”
```

Comment out your OLD document root with a '#', such that it will look like:

```
#DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs”
```

Then, repeat those changes for the Directory path:

```
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/bin”>
#DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs”
```

Stop/Restart MAMP.  For good measure, try loading local server in your browser, it shouldn't work.

Then, undo everything above and change your document and directory roots back to their originals.

Stop/Restart MAMP.  Try navigating to localhost/phpmyadmin or localhost:8888/phpmyadmin again.

Not sure exactly why, but it seems to trigger MAMP to behave itself.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

How I got it working was to click on WebStart(airplane symbol) on MAMP.
Then under MySQL section click on phpMyAdmin in the line "You can administer your MySQL databases with phpMyAdmin."