# MAMPPRO forbidden access to phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp, mamp-pro

Im having an issue getting my database from localhost to public web.
When i use my opened port it gives the message that its working but when i wanna open phpmyadmin i dont have access.

[MAMPPRO confirming Port is good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGThb.png)

[MAMPPRO settings (when set to 127.0.0.1 it works good)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7eB1.png)

[Own named server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLQgP.png)

[No premission to access phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8dWl.png)

If anyone can help big thank you

Comment: a 403 is a webserver error. Check the permissions in Apache. P.S. PhpMyAdmin is unlikely to be running on port 3306 - that's the port which the mysql server normally runs on. Did you really set it up like that??

Comment: Yes it is set up like this. but doesnt seem to work. Can you please help me set it up coorectly

Comment: I suggest using a standard HTTP port like 80, as the first idea. Don't use a port which is the default port for another service entirely.

Comment: Okay thank you. changed the port but still got the 403 error.

Comment: next, check that the account which apache runs under has read&execute permission to the filesystem folder where phpmyadmin is installed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094534/getting-to-phpmyadmin-with-mamp might also help you, potentially